# How can I rewrite my code to bind a collection element in code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

How can I write Binding from XAML in my code to bind my collection element?

```
<GridViewColumn Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PageConfidences[0], StringFormat=p1}">
...
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what PageConfidences is, you may have to write a value converter.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ed707380-f14f-40e1-8a79-bfb9a445a7fa/

Comment: Thank you. A really quick and fine solution for such a kind of problem.

Comment: `Path=` does absolutely nothing.